# Use of Base.Hashtbl with tuple key

Tags: ocaml

I'm new to ocaml.  I want to use int * int tuple as the key.  This is the tutorial being used, http://dev.realworldocaml.org/maps-and-hashtables.html .  Is there a module for tuples?  Can a module be defined using int * int?  The examples I've found seem to all derive from struct.

Following one of the suggestions I now have this code:

```
module IntPair = struct
  module T = struct
    type t = int * int
    let compare x y = Tuple2.compare ~cmp1:Int.compare ~cmp2:Int.compare x y
    let sexp_of_t = Tuple2.sexp_of_t Int.sexp_of_t Int.sexp_of_t
  end

  include T
  include Comparable.Make(T)
end

let my_table = Hashtbl.create(module IntPair);;
```

But I get the following error:
Error: Signature mismatch:
       ...
       The value `t_of_sexp' is required but not provided

What is t_of_sexp?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In OCaml using Base, how do you construct a set with elements of type \`int \* int\`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59265721/in-ocaml-using-base-how-do-you-construct-a-set-with-elements-of-type-int-int)

Comment: Short answer: There is a `Tuple2` module in `Core_kernel`, but not in `Base`.

Comment: @glennsl  Hashtbl.create(module Tuple2) yields the error: "The value `hash' is required but not provided"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`t_of_sexp` is the inverse of `sexp_of_t` and has similar helper functions in `Tuple2` and `Int` which you should be able to use. For `hash` you can just use `Hashtbl.hash`. Something like this should work:

```
module IntPair = struct
  module T = struct
    type t = int * int
    let compare x y = Tuple2.compare ~cmp1:Int.compare ~cmp2:Int.compare x y
    let sexp_of_t = Tuple2.sexp_of_t Int.sexp_of_t Int.sexp_of_t
    let t_of_sexp = Tuple2.t_of_sexp Int.t_of_sexp Int.t_of_sexp
    let hash = Hashtbl.hash
  end

  include T
  include Comparable.Make(T)
end

let my_table = Hashtbl.create(module IntPair);;
```

Comment: This seems to work.   But I had to move the let my_table ... statement into a function otherwise there is a compilation error because the type of the value is not defined.

Comment: So sexp_of_t and t_of_sexp are like serialization functions? Is there a way I can print out the contents of the Hashtable for debugging?

Comment: Indeed, it uses s-expressions as a serialization format. So you can serialize the hash table with `Hashtbl.sexp_of_t` and get a human readable string from that using `Sexp.to_string_hum`